# Setting up luarocks on windows 10

Tags: lua, luarocks

I am having a hard time to set up luarocks on windows so i can install packages with luarocks.

The official luarocks installation wiki doesn't help as it says the *all-in-one package* for windows includes an *INSTALL.BAT* that sets eveything up. The entire installation wiki is based on this *INSTALL.BAT*, but the *all-in-one package* doesn't contain this mysterious *INSTALL.BAT*.

What i have done so far is downloaded lua53 and the latest luarocks (3.3.1)
and put them in the following folder structure:

[image]

I've added *c:\lua\bin* and *c:\lua\luarocks* to PATH variable.
I've created a *config-5.3.lua* at location *C:\Program Files\luarocks* and *C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\luarocks*

The content of both *config-5.3.lua* is:

```
variables = {
    LUA_LIBDIR = "C:\\lua\\lualibs"
}
```

Now when i want to install a package with luarocks i get the following Error:

[image: 1591958890852.png]

What am i suppose to do with the LUA_LIBDIR?
I thought it is already set in *config-5.3.lua*?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried inserting the lua binary inside the luarocks folder?

I have the same problem where it tells me the `LUA_INCDIR` and `LUA_INBDIR` has an error, but once I've added `LUA` binary inside the luarocks folder then it got rid of the `LUA_INBDIR` error. If you have `LUA_INCDIR` after that, then I can't help since I'm also stuck with the problem.

[image]

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue with the LUA_INCDIR? I am still stuck on this part. Or does someone else have a solution for this problem?

Comment: To solve this could you let me know what is the number in the `#define LUA_VERSION_NUM` in line 21 of lua.h in the include directory

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this work by doanloading the appropriate headers and setting the LUA_INCDIR.  More details at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77092142/1873897).